# Why clang-formatter breaks line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang-format

This is the `clang-format` file:

```
BasedOnStyle : Chromium 
AlignTrailingComments : true 
BreakBeforeBraces : Allman 
ColumnLimit : 0 
IndentWidth : 4 
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks : false 
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty : true 
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList : true 
PointerBindsToType : false 
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments : 1 
TabWidth : 8 
UseTab : Never
```

Why it breaks lines here?

[image]

Using this command: `clang-format | ls PFB/*.[hm] | xargs clang-format -i -style=file`

Answer (score 0):

I've fiddled a ton with this and I don't think you are going to get good results basing the style off anything. I have: `Language: ObjC` and much the same settings as you.